# In French, can you say « passer X à côté de Y » to express the idea of "I wanna stay with you forever"?

Tags: expressions

I would perhaps use « auprès » or « avec »:

> Tu es la personne **auprès de** laquelle je veux **passer** le restant de mes jours.

But herein lies the question. Can you swap in « à côté » that at least has a similar meaning to the other two?

> Tu es la personne **à côté de** laquelle je veux **passer** le restant de mes jours.

Or is it better not to couple « à côté » with the verb « passer » in this instance, since the expression might be misinterpreted as the meaning of « rater », for one thing? The direct object « le restant de mes jours » might suggest otherwise, but I wonder if there remains some ambiguity?

Comment: Strange that noone mentionned that the idiomatic expression is "aux côtés de", "à tes côtés".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of grammar, both sentences are correct, and so is the sentence suggested by Laure.

However, as someone mentioned, there is an expression, written "**aux côtés de**", that would fit perfectly in this context. This expression is the figurative version of "*à côté de*". It means "*to be at someone's side, but not litterally*". In your example, you don't need to be next to your beloved one all the time to be considered as "à ses côtés". This very subtle difference is discussed [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%C3%A0-c%C3%B4t%C3%A9-de-au-c%C3%B4t%C3%A9-de-aux-c%C3%B4t%C3%A9s-de.938790/).

In my opinion, "*aux côtés de*" implies a form of permanent support that you give to the other person. It means that whatever happens, you are standing next to him/her, no matter if you are with him/her physically or not. For this reason, this is the expression I would choose in your very context.

> Tu es la personne **aux côtés** de laquelle je veux passer le restant de mes jours.

Answer (score 2):

Moi je ne dirais ni l'un ni l'autre, mais :

> Tu es celui / celle avec qui j'ai envie de passer le restant de mes jours.

Ceci dit, ***auprès de laquelle*** serait le bon choix dans le contexte amoureux. Et dans aucun des cas il ne peut y avoir d’ambiguïté sur le sens de *rater*.

Comment: Moi qui craignais qu’on s'emmêle les pinceaux avec la locution « passer à côté de » et pense que je ne veux pas croiser son chemin ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

"auprès de" really means "with you"

"à côté de" is more like, standing next to you, or sitting in the train, it's less romantic! It does not really make sense in this sentence in french

Comment: C'est exactement ce dont je me doutais. Merci. ;) Ce serait comme si je passais tout mon temps à épier les moindres gestes de mon amoureuse !